# Raise Event When ListBox range is Changed

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, range

I have a `ListBox` that is always populated by first calling `ListBox.Items.Clear()` then calling `ListBox.Items.AddRange(num);`

Is there an event that is raised every time the range is changed?

(I saw similar questions to this, but as they pertained to more of the selected index, the proposed solutions do not help me. My list box isn't selectable)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx -- Have a look at the Events.

Comment: If you manually add your items from only one place, for what do you need an event? Just call the event handler after adding the items. If you are using bindings, you can listen for the `DataSourceChanged` event.

Comment: @WeSt it is being added from multiple places

Comment: [Lars has a really good solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860467/events-for-adding-removing-items-in-a-listbox-c-net). At first it looks as if it not applicable but maybe it is..If not I guess you'll have to give subclaasing a shot..

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is an event for this.  But you can create a subclass of your listbox class and override the AddRange method to call your new event that you create to handle this (and then call the base classes addRange method).